# nbqa-flake8: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position

Tags: ipynb

Good afternoon!

I'm trying to set up a pre-commit to check the .ipynb file.
It works `nbqa flake8 --ignore=E402,W291,W293 --max-line-length=120 --show-source Project.ipynb` in command line, the same thing done with

.pre-commit-config.yaml:

```
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/nbQA-dev/nbQA
  rev: 1.7.0
  hooks:
    - id: nbqa-flake8
      args: ['--ignore="E402,W291,W293', '--max-line-length=120', '--show-source', '--output-file=output.txt']
```

or configuration file:

```
[flake8]
extend-ignore = E402,W291,W293 
max-line-length= 120 
show_source = True
statistics = True
```

does not work.

```
C:\Users\yesno\.cache\pre-commit\repoxlk1smrm\py_env-python3.11\Lib\site-packages\autopep8.py:182: DeprecationWarning: lib2to3 package is deprecated and may not be able to parse Python 3.10+
  from lib2to3.pgen2 import tokenize as lib2to3_tokenize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\yesno\.cache\pre-commit\repoxlk1smrm\py_env-python3.11\Scripts\nbqa.EXE\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\yesno\.cache\pre-commit\repoxlk1smrm\py_env-python3.11\Lib\site-packages\nbqa\__main__.py", line 875, in main
    return _main(cli_args, configs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yesno\.cache\pre-commit\repoxlk1smrm\py_env-python3.11\Lib\site-packages\nbqa\__main__.py", line 784, in _main
    sys.stdout.write(output.out)
  File "C:\Users\yesno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2135-2141: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried to do this from:

- the command line (work)
- pass the parameters in .pre-commit-config.yaml (work without --show-source)
- pass the parameters in the configuration file. (work without --show-source)

The error is very similar to this one: https://github.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/1381

What can I do to fix this?